# Prototype pattern create new property

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to share `socket.io` to my property, not sure why it not working...

My 1st file, `MessageController.js`:

```
function MessageController() {
};

MessageController.prototype.io = "";

MessageController.prototype.sendMessageAction = function (req, res) {
    console.log(this.io);

}

module.exports = new MessageController();
```

In another file `router.js` I have like this:

```
var messageController = require('./controllers/MessageController');


module.exports = function (expressApp, router, io) {
    console.log(io); 

   messageController.io = io;

    router.post('/dashboard/message', messageController.sendMessageAction);

    return router;
};
```

Here is how I require `router.js`:

```
module.exports = function (expressApp, io) {
    var router = system.express.Router();

    router = require('./dashboard/router.js')(expressApp, router, io);

    return router;


};
```

And when I call route `this.io` property returns `undefined` anyone know what is problem?

Comment: it looks like you might be setting it to undefined 
in router.js 

try :

 module.exports = function (expressApp, router, io) {
       console.log(io);    // undefined
       ....
    };

Comment: It is not udefined bacause, I replaced `io` with string but same result...

Comment: you replaced it before setting it in router.js
did you try logging it, like i suggested ?

Comment: Yes, I put: `messageController.io = 'test';` and it still return undefined, I also try to log it it returns `io` object

Comment: edit your question show me where you logged it

Comment: edited, check now

Comment: and it logs 'test' right ?

show us how you require router.js

Comment: Added in main post...

Comment: It is wird it looks like property io not even created...

Comment: do console.log(this) 
lets see who 'this' is . 
(It's suppose to be that instance you created by just in case)

Comment: Never export a `new …`. If you want only a single instance (static singleton), just use an object literal for creating it. Otherwise, export the class constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is a misunderstanding on how scope works in JavaScript. When the `router` calls `messageController.sendMessageAction` it uses a binding to it. e.g:

```js
callback(res, req, next)
```

In this case, the current scope **is not** `messageController`. So `this` does not refer to `messageController`. If you want `this` to be *bound* to `messageController` you must *bind* `sendMessageAction` to it.

```js
// Using Function#bind
router.post(
  '/dashboard/message',
  messageController.sendMessageAction.bind(messageController)
)

// Using a closure
router.post(
  '/dashboard/message',
  (req, res) => messageController.sendMessageAction(req, res)
)
```

Comment: So who is 'this' here ?
router ?
because the method was delelgated to him ?